# Sincronização de tabelas PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Precisava de uma ajuda no PHP My Admin sobre sincronizar campos em diferentes tabelas e na mesma base de dados.
**Por exemplo:**
**Base de dados: Teste**
**Tabela teste1**
colunas:
- col1
- col2
**Tabela teste2**
colunas:
- col1
- col3
Precisava que, quando fosse inserido valores na tabela 1, a tabela 2 ficasse com a coluna 3 nula e as colunas 1 iguais.

**Nota:** Uso o PHP My Admin versão 4.7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um TRIGGER para isso, veja abaixo:

Tabela1:

```
CREATE TABLE Teste1(
   ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   Nome NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Tabela 2:

```
CREATE TABLE Teste2(
   Teste1ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
   Algumacoisa NVARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT FK_Teste1_em_Teste2
   FOREIGN KEY (Teste1ID)
   REFERENCES Teste1.ID
);
```

Trigger usado para inserir novo registro após um INSERT na Tabela1:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Gatilho_Teste1
AFTER INSERT
ON Teste1 FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO Teste2(Teste1ID) VALUES(NEW.ID);
```

Veja Funcionando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após cada registro ser inserido  na tabela1 o trigger é disparado e insere o msm id na tabela 2, já na coluna3 você solicitou null, então só declarar o `DEFAULT NULL` na construção da tabela.

Comment: Olá estive a testar esta solução e não consegui colocar no phpmyadmin este `trigger`. Diz que existe um erro próximo ao `AS` na linha 4 e dá erros na criação das tabelas através da consola. Podia ajudar-me com o phpmyadmin?

Comment: @Simplecoder foi mal ae pela demora, para atualizei, encontrei 2 problemas na minha resposta que ja foram sanados. 1º tinha uma vírgula a mais na primeira tabela. 2º o AS no TRIGGER creio que digitei por impulso. Não responde antes pois estava acendo a comunidade por aplicativo e não tinha como testar. Mais esta tudo certo agora.

Comment: Obrigado, isto funcionou mais ou menos da maneira que você indicou. Ainda não consegui criar a tabela `teste2` usando o código SQL, mas criei usando o assistente e não foi necessário definir uma chave estrangeira.

Comment: @Simplecoder está funcionando corretamente, sinceramente não sei o que vc está fazendo ai há não ser que post o print do erro. A Chave estrangeira serve para verificar e garantir a integridade referencial da tabela. Um motivo para ela não funcionar pode ser a `ENGINE`.